# Keep the code Running In background in Ios

Tags: iphone, ios4, background-process

I want to run code in background for an infinite time and not for only 10 mins. I am not using Music or GPS or Viop. I want to show continuous local notification with some time interval. I have achieved the work with constraint of 10 mins. Please help.

Comment: Do you want to publish your app to the App Store?  If the answer is yes, I don't think this is possible: Apple's not going to let your app on the store the way it is described here (using background resources but not in Audio, Location, or VOIP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @phooze said was right.To show continuous local notification with some time interval use [repeatInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval) property.

Comment: I did try to use this. However simulator hangs. Can you help on this.

Comment: Means no event recognised or then i cannot deploy a new application. i need to reset it to get working from menu.

Comment: I will check and will be back.

Comment: I did check it gave problem earlier as the method was not correct. Now i want to give this in interval of 30 seconds. So i tried using two notification. With time duration x and x+30. I also gave repeat interval of 1 minute. however it works only for the first time.